# Photoshop plug-in: Access layer information in C++

Tags: c++, plugins, adobe, photoshop, layer

I am currently writing a plug-in for Photoshop to save layer data into an .xml file, so far I've had no trouble (other than the bleak Adobe SDK) finding information such as layer names, the amount of layers, the document name, the dimensions of the document and more. However, I cannot find out how to access the dimensions and position of a layer, the SDK has been no help and I was wondering if someone had any experience on this?
For reference, here is the code to access the name of the layer:

```
    OSErr PIGetLayerName(const int32 index, string & layerName)
    {
        Handle h = NULL;

        OSErr error = sPSProperty->getPropertyProc(kPhotoshopSignature, 
                                           propLayerName,
                                           index, NULL, &h);

        if (!error && h != NULL)
        {
            error = HandleToString(h, layerName);
            sPSHandle->Dispose(h);
        }

        return error;
    }
```

"propLayerName" and "kPhotoshopSignature" are defined in "PIProperties.h" (included in the SDK)
similar definitions of "propTitle" (to get the document name) are also there.
However there are no such definitions for finding the dimensions, bounds, width and height - whatever it may be called - of the layer.

If anyone has any information I would be extremely grateful if you could post it.

Thanks in advance,
Harry